# how not to use an element more that once?

Tags: c++

So here's the problem: you input n(2 < n < 10^6); k(-10^9 < k < 10^9); n number of integers from -10^9 to 10^9.
The goal is to find how many pairs there are in n number of integers, of which sum equals to k and print it. You CANNOT use the elements more than once. Integers can be repeated. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    int numbers[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
         for (int l = j + 1; l < n; l++){
             if (numbers[j] + numbers[l] == k){
                 result += 1;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

How do you skip the used element?
Example 1:
input:

```
5 4
2 2 2 2 2
```

Output should be:
2(since 2+2, 2+2)
Mine is: 
4(2+2, 2+2, 2+2, 2+2)

Example 2:
input:

```
5 4
1 3 5 2 -1
```

My output:
2(since 1+3=4, 5+(-1)=4)- which is correct
The only problem I have is i cant skip the used elements.

Comment: 1) we do not do homework 2) if this is not, please tell us what is going wrong

Comment: sort input, use then a linear solution (2 iterators, one from the start, one from the end).

Comment: 1) It is not homework, been trying to solve this puzzle for a long time(I'm new to coding). 2) All elements can be used only once, but , as you can see, in the next for loop the already used element still works. The problem is I cannot "clear" the elements so it's still usable, resulting in false result

Comment: `int numbers[n];` is invalid C++ as it use VLA extension. use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: if it is not an homework, than the easiest solution (and the oldest) is to use a flag. The flag is always 0 but, when an element is found then it is set to 1. You can check for a new element only if the flag is to zero. When the check on the sequence is done, remember to put the flag again to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array in which you save whether an element has been used or not (Like it was mentioned in the comments):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//array with 10^6 elements, 
//(== max number of numbers)
bool used[1000000];

int main(){
    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    int numbers[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        //check if element has been used
         if(used[j] == 1) {
            continue;
         }
         for (int l = j + 1; l < n; l++){
            //check if element has been used
            if(used[l] == 1 ) {
                continue;
            }
             if (numbers[j] + numbers[l] == k){
                 //mark elements as used
                 used[j] = 1;
                 used[l] = 1;
                 result += 1;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is sort input, and process linearly from both sides.
(That also reduce complexity from `O(n²)` to `O(n log n)`)

```
int main(){
    int n;
    int k;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin >> k;
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    for (auto& e : v){
        std::cin >> e;
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (v.empty())
    {
        std::cout << 0;
        return 0;
    }

    std::size_t counter = 0;
    auto left = 0;
    auto right = v.size() - 1;
    while (left < right) {
        const auto sum = v[left] + v[right];
        if (sum < k) {
            ++left; 
        } else if (k < sum) {
            --right;
        } else { // sum == k
            // It is here that we may have special handling to handle duplicates
            // when v[left] == v[left+1].
            // Here, it is simple, no special cases :-)
            ++counter;
            ++left;
            --right;
        }
    }
    std::cout << counter;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/LRpD7F)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! But some outputs seem to be incorrect. What’s the limits like 2<n<10^6 and -10^9 <k<10^9 for?

Comment: `int` is wrong type for those limits, you need at least `std::int32_t`. Those limits are here to know types to use and expected complexity.

Comment: ah, I see. Also when I run the code on C++11 it says "24:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]". What's this about?

Comment: It should be `std::size_t left = 0;` as `auto` is deduced as `int`, whereas `right` has same type than `v.size()`.